# Modify return data then returning promise in typescript / ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, promise

I have a really simple question but cannot get the answer myself.
In my ionic app I'm fetching data from a database. I want to 
modify the data comming from my

```
sqlite.execute(): Promise<Article[]>
```

then returning the promise, so that the function in the view component just have to show the data by:

```
this.controllercomponent.getSearchResults( SearchTerm ).then( Res => this.Articles = Res );
```

By now I'm solving this with a nested promise, but ionic returns an error:

```
return new Promise<Article[]>( Resolve => 
    {
    this.dbGetSearchResults( SearchTerm ).then( Res => 
      { 
      //Modify articles array

      Resolve(Res);
      })
    .catch( Err => { this.showAlert( "Error fetching db data:", JSON.stringify(Err)); });
    });
```

Error:

```
{
"originalErr": {},
"__zone_symbol__currentTask": {
  "type": "microTask",
  "state": "notScheduled",
  "source": "Promise.then",
  "zone": "<root>",
  "cancelFn": null,
  "runCount": 0
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you need to wrap this in a `new Promise`?

Comment: Is one promise enough though? Just skip `then` on the view component and `return Res;` in controller component? May I return the Result inside the `then` callback of "dbGetSearchResults" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to avoid `Promise` constructor if it's not needed.

```
function f() {
    return Promise.resolve()
        .then(()=>this.dbGetSearchResults( SearchTerm ))
        .then((Res)=>{
            /*Modify articles array*/
            return Res;
        })
        .catch( Err => { this.showAlert( "Error fetching db data:", JSON.stringify(Err)); });
}
```